# How to find the English words "Shipping" and "Review & Payments"

Tags: magento2

In the screenshots below, you can see the strings "Shipping" and "Review & Payments". I want to translate these strings to Chinese, but I don't know where I can find the source of these strings.

picture 1
[image]

picture 2
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a .csv file in the `vendor > [Vendor] > [Theme] > src > i18n` folder. The name of the .csv file has to be named according to your language (in this case Chinese), I think it is zh_CN.csv in this case.

In this file, you write your translations like this:

```
"Original string","Translation","type","Location"
```

For example:

```
"Newsletters","Nieuwsbrieven","module","Magento_Customer"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a directory `app/i18n/<Vendorname>/language_zh_hans_cn` (or whatever you want to call it)

Issue command:

`bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases --output "app/i18n/<Vendorname>/language_zh_hans_cn/zh_Hans_CN.csv" --magento`

This will collect all the translatable phrases in csv file `zh_Hans_CN.csv` and place it in the specified path. Make changes to the csv file as per your requirement and when ready issue command:

```
bin/magento i18n:pack app/i18n/<Vendorname>/language_zh_hans_cn/zh_Hans_CN.csv -d zh_Hans_CN
```

This will deploy the translations from your file.

clear the cache etc and you should see your changes.

PS: There is a Chinese language pack if you want to use it for reference or full install http://bit.ly/2izuj1m

Answer (score 0):

Or just translate it inline.

Go to:

```
Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Translate inline -> Enabled to storefront 'yes'
```

Clear cache, and refresh the page.

Do the translation, save.

Set "Enabled on storefront "No".

Clear cache, and refresh.